# How to delete Netlify deployed branch

Tags: git, netlify

**Scenario**: A new branch is created and desired code changes applied. The branch is later deployed to Netlify with a custom (Branch) URL. After testing, pull request is made and a *deploy-preview* is also deployed on Netlify with another custom URL. Then, merge request is approved and successfully merged the branch is fully deleted.

**Consequences**: However, even then the *deploy-preview* and *branch-deploy* specific deploys remain up and published.

**Question**:

- How does one remove (purge) *branch-specific* deploy from Netlify?
- Bonus: How does one remove (purge) *deploy-preview* deploy from Netlify?

Comment: Although the information to delete a site is good information, it does not answer your question correctly. "How to delete Netlify deployed branch". Marking that as the correct answer is going to confuse someone.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right. It does answer the question, it provides an option to delete it. Each deployment has a unique ID, thus with an API call, you can remove it.

Comment: Yes, the API calls will allow you to permanently delete a (WHOLE) site. I have not seen a documented API endpoint for deleting a specific deploy. That is the specific question you asked above. I was to believe by your comments in my answer that you were trying to delete specific branch deploys so they would not be crawled, but leave the production deploy still working.

Comment: You were right. I mistook siteId for deployId. I have tested myself and the given Endpoint is specifically for the whole site. Thank you for bringing this up!

Comment: Yeah, I think I will put in an issue to see if a feature can be added to delete the deploy using the ID the same as a site. Thanks for understanding and confirming yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently (04/16/2018) there is not a documented method to delete a specific deploy on Netlify. There are methods to stop a branch from being seen (see notes) that you can implement s part of your build workflow.

[Contact support](https://www.netlify.com/support) to have something sensitive removed.

***NOTE:***

- Netlify adds an HTTP header `x-robots-tag: noindex` to the response headers on all Deploy Previews (built for a Pull Request), so those won't be indexed.
- You can password protect branch deploys by selectively following: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/04/07/selective-password-protection/
  Note that it requires planning;  you have to set this up before you
  deploy:

Comment: Fortunately, have set up dynamic meta robots element to prevent indexing, so will leave for now. However, regarding password protection, it's worth noting that it requires a paid plan.

Comment: That is not the password protection being talked about in the article. They are talking about putting a header record to require access and stop previews from being seen.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to share an example? I can't seem to find which free option you're referring to...

Comment: Just wanted to add that the Basic Auth feature mentioned in that article is no longer available on the free tier.

Answer (score 2):

As of now only Netlify support can help to remove the deployed and published branch and it's created netlify domain.

Here you can see Netlify Support Engineer's comment in Netlify community.
https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-delete-branch-deploy/838/13

Answer (score 0):

they added a new Danger zone section in general settings where you can delete your site

Comment: This question is about deleting the branch preview deploys and NOT the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

FOLLOW THESE SIMPLE STEPS

1. Click on to the site you want to delete
   2 . Click on `site setting`
2. Scroll down, You will see `Danger zone`, beneath it there is delete button.
3. You are done

Comment: Hi Tesh Aych. That you for contribution, this answer however is a duplicate of @Achraf ELKHANDOULI's.

Comment: Hi! This question is about deleting the branch preview deploys and NOT the site itself.